# Ubercart Drupal add product to cart from external landing page

Tags: forms, drupal, external, product, ubercart

is it possible to have a form on an external landing page, that when submitted, adds a product to Ubercart cart and proceeds to the checkout page?

I am guessing it would be a matter of submitting product details, such as ID's etc to the cart, but I have no experience with Ubercart and initial research has come up empty.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a module that lets you generate URLs for your ubercart to add products to the shopping cart.

https://drupal.org/project/uc_cartlinksbuilder

You can download the Drupal 6, or 7 dev version from that link and install it on your site. Once the user submits the form you can generate a link and redirect the user to the new URL.